# Controlling GoPro with URL commands

Tags: android, http, url

I have a GoPro Hero3 Black Edition and after reading their user forums, I got these 2 url commands that can control the shutter button while the GoPro is acting as a hotspot.

> Record/shoot Command
>
> On `http://10.5.5.9:80/bacpac/SH?t=WIFIPASSWORD&p=%01`
>
> Off `http://10.5.5.9:80/bacpac/SH?t=WIFIPASSWORD&p=%00`

I have tried using the URLs in my Nexus 7's Chrome Browser but I want to integrate these 2 commands in a button in my Android app when my Nexus 7 connects via wifi to the GoPro.

How do I do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just bookmark the urls and place shortcuts on your homescreen. No need to build an app.

Comment: Look in the SDK samples, there are several which access a URL.  You wil need to connect that up to some buttons.  And make sure you are using a mechanism to delegate the network operation to something other than the UI thread.

Comment: I really need to integrate it into my app so I have to know how.

Answer (score 1):

It's not that tough. Create an activity class and a couple of buttons to fire the HTTP commands.
Keep in mind that these are network calls and have to be made from a separate background thread (not the main thread).

```
btnToggle.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {     
                // Toggle the camera power
                new OperateCamera().execute();
            }
        });
```

Create a new AsyncTask  class:

```
class OperateCamera extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

            protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls) {
                return triggerShutter();
            }

            // Method to trigger the shutter
            boolean triggerShutter(){

                try {
                    // Make network call
                    return true;
                }
                catch (Exception e) {                    
                    return false;
                }
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the legacy [URLConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) or some lib like [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) to access these urls and trigger the shutter. I'd recommend the second ;)